# ASP.NET Application performance counters all set 0 when accessed remotely

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I want to check Requests/sec counter remotely using perfmon. Everything is working ok locally but when I want see this counter using remote computer I don't see any instances and all counters are set to 0.

Remote registry service is running, permissions seems to be all right.I do not have any idea what is wrong. I work on 3 enviroments - production / staging / test. On production we are still using .NET and I can access counters remotely. On staging and test we're using .NET 4.5 and we have problems there.

It's strange but when I want to access counters from local machine using it's network address (not local 127.0.0.1 but for example 10.88.2.4) I don't see counters to :(.

Other counters (Processor for example) are visible locally and remotely.